# How to test APEX rest API in Visual Studio

Tags: apex, rest-service, visualstudiocode

Is it possible / How to test Apex REST method from Visual Studio Code?

From workbench we can test from REST Explorer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very clear what, precisely, you're asking. This answer assumes that you mean something along the lines of "How can I make a call from VSC to an Apex web service?"

The answer is maybe, but that's not officially supported by the Salesforce-developed plugins or extensions for SFDX or Visual Studio Code (to the best of my knowledge). You'd need to rifle through VSCode extensions to see if one provides the functionality you require (which, at the very least, would be something like cURL).

My opinion is that if you're CLI-oriented, you already have a tool you like to use to do this.
If you're GUI-oriented, VSCode isn't going to provide a good experience for you.
In either case, I doubt VSCode is the right tool for the job. Don't try to drive a nail with a screwdriver. Stick to the workbench, or a tool dedicated to the job (like cURL or Postman)